# Element only on one page using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an Angular website which has a structure like this:

```
<body ng-app>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main" ng-view="website"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

How can I, use Angular or not, insert a div that's between my header div and ng-view div only on the home page?
It will be like this (only for the home page):

```
<body ng-app>
<div class="header"></div>
<div>This is the extra div that only exists on home page. But it's outside the ng-view scope.</div>
<div class="main" ng-view="website"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a different ng-view only used for the home page route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within the controller that you are using routing set a scope value based on your routeParam that indicates what page you are on:

```
<body ng-app controller="routeController">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div ng-show="routeParam.page='home'">This is the extra div that only exists on home page. But it's outside the ng-view scope.</div>
    <div class="main" ng-view="website"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the most transparent and requires no additional js +1.

Answer (score 3):

This is the template:

```
<div ng-if="homepage"> ... </div>
```

And here you listen for route changes:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){

  function isHomepage(){
    // check it
  }

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous){
    $rootScope.homepage = isHomepage(current);
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace that special div with a directive, and watch for route changes. It's much more declarative than other solutions.  Something like this...

```
app.directive('homeHeader', function() {
 return {
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     template: '<div ng-if="isHome" ng-transclude></div>',
     link: function($scope) {
          $scope.isHome = //init
          $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
           //do something   
          });
     }
 }
});

<body ng-app>
<div class="header"></div>
<home-header>This is the extra div that only exists on home page. But it's outside the ng-view scope.</home-header>
<div class="main" ng-view="website"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Read up on $route here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: I do not believe that this is the proper use for a directive. Consider allowing the consumer of this directive to put the content of the div inline. `<home-header>This is the extra div...</home-header>`

Comment: This is precisely the proper use of a directive.  Using ng-transclude to allow in-lining of the content is fine, but that doesn't make the directive 'improper'.

Comment: imho: directives are about declaring behavior not content. In this case there is both behavior and implicit content being declared. I feel that is improper and that the two should be separate.